# interpolate with glmer where new data is a Raster Stack and model is fixed effects with lat and long as independent predictors

Tags: r, interpolation, raster

I am trying to make a raster file to predict where species will occur. The model that I want to run is:

```
glmer(colorSymbol ~ snow.cover_sc + bio2_sc + bio3_sc + alt_sc + y + x + (1|spsCode), family = binomial, data = data)
```

It is a mixed effects model with lat (x) and long (y) as independent predictors as well as various environmental covariates. x and y are geographical coordinates. Since x and y are independent predictors I am trying to use the interpolate function in the `raster` package. However, the help file for interpolate gives `gstat` (`gstat` package) or `Krige` (`fields` package) as example model objects.

So my first question is can a glmer serve as a model for the interpolate function? I realize that a glmer assumes independence between the predictors and tested for that to see if there was correlation between any of them and found none (<0.5).

My second question is if glmer can be the model object, what does the following error mean:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action,
>   xlev = object$xlevels) :    object is not a matrix In addition:
>   Warning message: closing unused connection 4

For context I get this error when I run the reduced model:

```
m4<- glm(colorSymbol ~ bio_2 + alt + x + y, family = binomial, data = data)
```

and create a raster stack of bio_2 and alt. Links to files below: (Note they can also be accessed via worldclim(dot)org/current (sorry can't post more than 2 links) and downloading ESRI 30 second grids.)

[alt raster file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B53lvIgbMqd7WHU1Xy1Rc3c2bmM)

[bio_2 raster file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B53lvIgbMqd7QUY5SVFkc0VTY2s)

Here is the full code:

```
data4<-structure(list(colorSymbol = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), bio_2 =           
structure(c(-1.65319533124791, 
5.12773277360962, -2.96563302896227, 2.13829135103802, 1.62789891303799, 
0.169634804466482, -0.049104811819245, -0.049104811819245,      
-0.049104811819245, 
-0.049104811819245, -0.267844428104972, 0.315461215323633,   
0.315461215323633, 
-0.63241045524785, -0.63241045524785, 0.315461215323633, -0.122018017247821, 
-0.049104811819245, -0.413670838962123, 0.169634804466482), .Dim = c(20L, 
1L)), alt = structure(c(0.751340496188818, 4.17865221830445, 
-0.118372064874358, -0.554302064617135, 1.86371359898073,  
0.0126216788907128, 
-0.595103394642321, -0.595103394642321, -0.558596941461892,   
-0.573629010418539, 
-0.0840130501163067, -0.0625386658925246, 0.0620127626054117, 
2.11925877124374, 2.11925877124374, -0.124814380141493, -0.543564872505244, 
-0.719654823140258, 0.495795323925811, 0.20803857532713), .Dim = c(20L, 
1L)), y = structure(c(0.0353970033327643, 1.83610974064461,  
-4.82625744580285, 
-4.36879939725431, 1.11073398331965, 0.101128667461893, 0.171636464096401, 
0.171636497654332, 0.168280671013401, 0.168839981046544, 0.173873670671044, 
0.10507991246954, 0.0997146033725779, 0.0106082967555351,   
0.0106082967555351, 
0.105639188944753, 0.182263153378545, 0.186305172589088, 0.133466968853809, 
0.10507991246954), .Dim = c(20L, 1L)), x = structure(c(3.73193203850492, 
-3.74207501883321, 1.93312018034606, -3.43881737052527, -1.87240343109311, 
-0.289046352405738, 0.13805360014565, 0.13805360014565, 0.0955082550467424, 
0.0997628661381006, 0.00616320902913118, 0.0869992881355855, 
-0.236861953199331, -0.103499155724443, -0.103499410996004, 
0.0912538992269437, 
0.0997628661381006, 0.0498381307812604, 0.220158634177113,     
0.0784903212244285
), .Dim = c(20L, 1L))), .Names = c("colorSymbol", "bio_2", "alt", 
"y", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

library("lme4")
library("raster")
library("rgdal")
library("RArcInfo")

m7 = glm(colorSymbol ~ bio_2 + alt + x + y, family = binomial, data = data4)
#write model

alt<-raster("alt.ovr")
bio_2<-raster("bio_2.ovr")
#import rasters

rasstack<-stack(alt, bio_2)
#make raster stack

test<-raster::interpolate(rasstack, m7)
#try and interpolate model
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I edited my post to hopefully provide a reproducible example. Please let me know if I should add or change anything else.